# What nifi processors Should be used to convert Xml file to Json and insert a particular content of that file into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi, data-conversion, processor

What NiFi processor are required to convert xml to json & insert particular data from that file to mysql database? How to configure needed processor?

Answer (score 2):

[PutDatabaseRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/) can be configured with an XML Reader, which will handle reading the XML and writing it to MySQL if you don't actually need to convert to JSON.

You can use [ConvertRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord/) with an XML Reader and a JSON Writer if you just want to turn your XML data into JSON.

Alternatively, you can use [UpdateRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html) with an XML Reader and a JSON Writer if you want to turn XML into JSON *and* modify values.

Comment: @Amruth Please update your question and include more details - what does your input data look like? what does the json look like? what does your table look like? what are you trying to insert to the table?

Comment: Input data is some Xml file, that is converted to Json file after that while using put database table processor in nifi, i need to mention table name, for that i need to create a table in mysql database (workbench) . To create table i need to mention columns, that column name should be from json file, which contains column name with its corresponding data. I want to know how to find the column names from the json file, to mention in mysql table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example is not valid `"EE56AS": "sdf":2`. Can you give a valid example?

Comment: Hello sdairs, thanks for reply. My json is a large file from that file i want to insert a particular content to mysql table. The file is in this format.(after converting xml to json) :-.   { "E1S" : { "seg":3, "sed" :5 upto sdf, "action" : 5 }, "E3D" : { "fgh" :67, "dre":89} how to insert seg of E1S to table (what is the column name of my table for this json) kindly help me . Looks it is in form of array how to insert to mysql . What conversion must be needed? Thanks